# How to get notification when a new device connected to android hotspot

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi

I want to get a notification when a device add or remove from hotspot.I have registered IntentFilter.addAction() to get the notifications, but its not triggering when a new device connected to the hotspot.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);


getActivity().registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: i hv asked before but no posible answers:) so +1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to 'getWifiState()' then if the result is  :

Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)  -- >  WIFI_STATE_DISABLING

Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)  -- > WIFI_STATE_DISABLED

Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)  -->  WIFI_STATE_ENABLING

Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)  -->  WIFI_STATE_ENABLED

Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)  -->  WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN

For other option check here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

If that's all you can just checkmark to my answer if i helped you , thank you !